# Unwanted comma in the tooltips when line breaking a label in ChartsJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have some plots with very long labels. I used the answers found in this site to break the labels in new lines.

This is an example of my labels:

```
labels: [ 'Utensilios para escrita e artes','Faz de conta','Jogos',['Materiais não estruturado','/de largo alcançe/recicláveis'],['Repertório artístico-cultural e','científico de diferentes','origens étnico-raciais'],'Livros de história','Materiais para pesquisa',],
```

I'm integrating ChartsJS with PHP and generating multiple charts dynamically. All the info needed to create the graphs is stored in a DB.

Since I need to display a % in all my values I'm using this callback for my tooltips

```
tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
                    return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label +': ' + tooltipItems.value + '%';
                }
            }
        },
```

The Issue is that in the tooltips the labels which had a line break using the nested arrays are shown with an unwanted comma, for example:
[image: Tooltip problem with one of the graphics]

Even if I don't use a custom tooltip the issue remains. Does this normally happen if we break labels using nested arrays? Is there any neat way to fix this?

I know there is a different way of breaking lines using \n alongside a plugin to split them but I couldn't get it to work. When I did it the \n was replaced with an extra space but not a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply also define a `tooltips.callbacks.title` function as follows and it will work. Sounds weird since the function does nothing but returning the label.

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {        
    title: (tooltipItems, data) => data.labels[tooltipItems[0].index],
    ... 
  }
},
```

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: [
      ['Utensilios para', 'escrita e artes'],
      ['Materiais não estruturado', 'de largo alcançe/recicláveis'],
      ['Repertório artístico-cultural e', 'científico de diferentes', 'origens étnico-raciais']
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: "A",
      data: [5, 8, 4],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: "B",
      data: [3, 5, 4],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: "C",
      data: [6, 5, 7],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {        
        title: (tooltipItems, data) => data.labels[tooltipItems[0].index],
        label: (tooltipItems, data) =>
          data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItems.value + '%'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: this no longer works for current version 4.2.1